# troubleshooting a printer problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, troubleshooting, printing

I have a large Kyocera Printer/Scanner/Copier machine in a office with three PCs (all plugged into a lan via router. The three PCs all have individual printers (inkJets) hooked directly via printer port. However, I would like to print from each PC to the large Kyocera Printer as well. I can't seem to do that. I have the drivers installed and updated, and the Kyocera shows in my printers section of my control panel.

All machines are Win XP

Can anyone give me a suggestive list of diagnostic steps to check to try and get this working?

How can I get the Ip address of all machines (PCs) and the Kyocera Printer on the Lan?

Comment: What protocols does the Kyocera printer speak? Can it talk NetBIOS or does it need to be reached via direct TCP/IP?

Comment: You might also identify the model of the Kyocera.

Comment: Kyocera printers generally fill me full of rage; I've had to monkey around with various versions of printers, manually configuring TCP/IP ports, etc. etc. to get it to work.  Support was abysmal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your printer is plugged directly into LAN and speaks plain TCP/IP:

[Connect a printer through a standard TCP/IP port](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/print_add_tcpip_port.mspx?mfr=true)

Your printer's manual should specify how to find out its current IP address, this is completely model-specific.

If your network uses DHCP, make sure to add a permanent lease for the printer ;) .

Comment: On the Kyocera you would normally need to configure the network settings on the printer itself before it can be used. That information is also in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a 3rd party print server. It will come with many utilities to troubleshoot. Then plug the print server into the printer.  It seems like the manufacture should work, but like others here, I have had problems with manufactures lan sharing. Even the big name brands. Just buy a printserver and this will be fixed in a day. 
I have even have used this cheap one. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156026 . It works better than the manufacture.